# Событие отжатия кнопки android

Tags: android

Можно ли как-то сделать событие на отжатие кнопки? Что-то вроде того, что, к примеру, если кнопка нажата - переменная будет равна 1, отжата - она будет равна 0.

Answer (score 5):

Определите глобально логическую переменную `isPressed`:

```
boolean isPressed = false;
```

и добавьте этот код в метод `onCreate`:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){  // Кнопка нажата
            isPressed = true;
        } else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){  // Кнопка отжата
            isPressed = false;
        }
        return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!